# How to reclassify Perl object

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I'm working with a few Perl packages, we'll call them `Some::Parser` and `Some::Data`. A `Some::Parser` object has methods to return objects of type `Some::Data`. I have written a class that extends the `Some::Data` class, let's call it `My::Data`. Objects of class `My::Data` are really just objects of class `Some::Data`, but with additional methods that make it easier to work with.

My problem is that I want to continue to use the `Some::Parser` class to do the hard work of parsing the data. As I said earlier, `Some::Parser` objects give me `Some::Data` objects. Once I have a `Some::Data` object in hand, is there any way to reclassify it as a `My::Data` object? How would I do this?

I'm totally willing to change my approach, assuming someone can suggest a better way of doing what I want to do, but writing my own parser is not something I'm interested in doing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This smells like a bit of a kludge. It might be time to rethink your strategy. For example, maybe you should write `My::Parser` which returns `My::Data` objects.

But if you don't want to do that, you can manually use `bless` to change an object's class:

```
my $obj = Some::Data->new;
bless $obj, 'My::Data';
```

See [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) in perldoc.

Comment: Since I'm still in the early stages, it's the perfect time to rethink my strategy...that's why I'm asking! I've been reading a lot about bless, and people have been warning about reblessing objects. Will this be less of an issue if the new object class extends the original class?

Comment: I think extending the original class is probably the best way to go. (As long as the original class is easily extensible. Don't go nuts if it's a small problem and re-blessing will solve it.) You can write your own constructor in your derived class which will bless the object. Your constructor may need to call the parent class constructor first and then re-bless, which amounts to the same thing but provides a nicer interface.

Comment: For converting a more complex, nested object I used the CPAN module  [Class::Rebless](http://search.cpan.org/~gaal/Class-Rebless-0.10/lib/Class/Rebless.pm).

Answer (score 7):

Probably the best way to handle something like this is for `Some::Parser` to provide a way to specify the class it should be using for data objects.  For example, [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) provides the `element_class` method.  If you want TreeBuilder to produce something other than `HTML::Element` nodes, you subclass `HTML::TreeBuilder` and override `element_class` to return your desired node class.  (The actual code in TreeBuilder is a bit more complex, because there was a different mechanism for doing this prior to HTML-Tree 4, and the new maintainer didn't want to break that.)

I take it that you didn't write `Some::Parser`, but perhaps it has this capability already.  If not, maybe its maintainer will accept a patch.  It should be a fairly simple change.  You'd just add a `data_class` method (`sub data_class { 'Some::Data' }`), and then change `Some::Data->new` to `$self->data_class->new`.  Then you can subclass `Some::Parser` to create `My::Parser`, and just override `data_class`.

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction when subclassing `Path::Class::*`, where `Path::Class::Dir` can return `Path::Class::File` objects, and vice versa.  Thanks to the good design of these two modules, I was able to override the `file_class()` and `dir_class()` methods in the respective modules.

Answer (score 5):

You can re`bless` anything.

Inheritance in Perl 5 is nothing more than searching `@ISA`.

Answer (score 3):

You can re-[bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) the returned object to whatever your heart desires:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Some::Data;
use strict; use warnings;

sub new { my $class = shift; bless { @_ } => $class }

sub a { $_[0]->{a} }

package My::Data;
use strict; use warnings;
use base 'Some::Data';

sub a_squared {
    my $self = shift;
    my $v = $self->a;
    return $v * $v;
}

package Some::Parser;
use strict; use warnings;

sub new { my $class = shift; bless { @_ } => $class }

sub parse { return Some::Data->new(a => 3) }

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

my $data = Some::Parser->new->parse;
bless $data => 'My::Data';

printf "%.1f\t%.1f\n", $data->a, $data->a_squared;
```

Alternatively, you can use @cjm's idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Some::Data;
use strict; use warnings;

sub new { my $class = shift; bless { @_ } => $class }

sub a { $_[0]->{a} }

package My::Data;
use strict; use warnings;
use base 'Some::Data';

sub a_squared {
    my $self = shift;
    my $v = $self->a;
    return $v * $v;
}

package Some::Parser;
use strict; use warnings;

sub new { my $class = shift; bless { @_ } => $class }

sub parse {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->data_class->new(a => 3);
}

sub data_class { $_[0]->{data_class} }

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

my $data = Some::Parser->new(data_class => 'My::Data')->parse;
printf "%.1f\t%.1f\n", $data->a, $data->a_squared;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider re-blessing venturesome. Once you have an object you can't really tell if it was created using its constructor ( usually Foo::new() ), or someone re-blessed some other object.

The problem is, some constructors are fat, this means they do a whole lotta more than just blessing something:

```
sub new {
    my $pkg = shift;
    my ($required) = @_;
    croak "Bad call" unless defined $required;
    _do_something_magic ($required);
    my $self = { 'foo' => $required };
    return bless $self, $pkg;
}
```

In this case your re-blessed object might not be the one you'll expect later in code.

One may consider constructors with "re-blessing" functionality build in. But such "object converters" will make the design even more complicated.

Stick to the basic definition: "An object is an instance of the class. Forever.".